# Opened collapse navbar not closing when clicking outside of navbar element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to close opened collapse navbar when clicking outside of navbar element. I am not sure why my navbar is not closing, so I decided to show you my code.

code:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-static-top">
 <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- for mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#head_menu" aria-expanded="false">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand">Project Name</a>
       </div>

      <!-- collects the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id = "head_menu">
        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
             <li> <a href = "#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">About CMMS</a></li>
             <li> <a href = "#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">Services</a></li>
             <li> <a href = "#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">JPS</a></li>
             <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">Contact</a></li>
        </ul> 
        <ul class ="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
             <li> <a href= "#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login </a> </li>
             <img id="jps" src="">
        </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
```

I have tried to follow this [answer](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5718/) but it did not work..

Answer (score 0):

You've too many errors with `data-target` and `data-toggle`

This may help you

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        Project Name
      </div>

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#head_menu">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="head_menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">About CMMS</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">JPS</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li> <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login </a> </li>
        <img id="jps" src="">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).click(function(event) {
    var clickover = $(event.target);
    var _opened = $(".navbar-collapse").hasClass("navbar-collapse in");
    if (_opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {
      $("button.navbar-toggle").click();
    }
  });
});
```

<kbd>[**LIVE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/5pnpor91/)</kbd>

Comment: there is strange behavior in my code and I suspect that one bootstrap link is missed or current links in my page are not the right links.I copy all my code and paste it in live demo you provided and it works fine, but when I create my own fiddle it did not work! can you tell me what bootstrap link did you include in external resource in your live demo? I would like to try and see what is gonna happen...